# REPLACE always creates a new row instead of replacing

Tags: mysql, replace

I've created a table that stores options for a custom branding plugin I am creating, but I can't seem to get `REPLACE` to work correctly.

If an option is not set, and I use the following, then the option is inserted as I would expect -

```
REPLACE INTO dd_admin_branding SET `option_name` = "show_custom_footer", `option_value` = "0";
```

However, if I was to then run the same query but with a different `option_value`, a new row is added, as opposed to the existing row being replaced -

```
REPLACE INTO dd_admin_branding SET `option_name` = "show_custom_footer", `option_value` = "1";
```

Reading the docs, it seems that I should be making both the `ID` (which is auto increment) and the `option_name` unique, which I am. Is anyone please able to tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Here is how my table is created (gathered when I export the table from the database)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dd_admin_branding` (
  `ID` smallint(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `option_name` varchar(64) character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `option_value` longtext character set latin1 collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`,`option_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation states that:

 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has **the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index**, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

It means, that **new row** (inserted by the REPLACE command) has to provide all values for PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY.

But the REPLACE command in the question references only `option_name` and `option_value`,
but doesn't provide `id` nor `id`+`option_name`. 
 In this case REPLACE works exactly like ordinary INSERT, it doesn't delete rows before inserting new ones.

Comment: Got it. I misinterpreted the description in the docs, and now that I removed the `ID` unique key, and just kept `option_name`, it's working. Thanks.